# How to rewrite a vector cross product?

Tags: vectors

Can this vector cross product $ \vec F = q \vec v \times \vec B $ be rewritten to $  \vec B = \vec F \times q \vec v $ ?

Edit: Take the special case, that all three vectors are orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the [vector triple product identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorTripleProduct.html) says

$$ (\vec {qv} \times \vec{B}) \times \vec{qv} = \|\vec{qv}\|^2 \vec B - (\vec{qv} \cdot \vec B) \vec{qv} $$

Assuming $\vec{qv}$ and $\vec{B}$ are linearly independent, this is $\vec B$ if and only if $\vec{qv}$ is a unit vector orthogonal to $\vec B$.

EDIT: In particular, if $\vec{qv}$ is orthogonal to $\vec B$, and is nonzero (but not necessarily a unit vector), you can write

$$ \vec B = \dfrac{\vec F \times \vec{qv}}{\|\vec{qv}\|^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform this task.

Notice that you are taking the **cross products** of vectors. If you are simply finding the magnitude of the values present, then you can simply rewrite to get:

$$F = qvB,\ B = \frac{F}{qv}$$

However, you are taking the cross products of vectors, which isn't a scalar quantity, it is a vector quantity. The direction of $F$ is determined using the right-hand rule. You cannot determine the direction of $B$ given the vectors $F$ and $v$. The only thing you can do is find the scalar value of $B$ by the formula above.