# How to rewrite a vector cross product with orthogonal vectors?

Tags: vectors

According to the question [how to rewrite the cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219103/how-to-rewrite-a-vector-cross-product) of orthogonal vectors

$ \vec F = q \vec v \times \vec B $ (1)

to $ \vec B = \cdots$

I get the answer $ \vec B = \dfrac{\vec F \times \vec{qv}}{\|\vec{qv} \|^2}$ (2).

Following this I find from the equation (2) $ q \vec v = \dfrac {|\vec {qv}\|^2 \vec B \times \vec F}{\|\vec {F}\|^2} $.

This has to go easier. How to rewrite $ q \vec v = \cdots$ direct from (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can take a [vector triple product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorTripleProduct.html) in this way - 
$$\vec{F}\times\vec{B}=(q\vec{v}\times\vec{B})\times\vec{B}$$
$$\vec{F}\times\vec{B}=(q\vec{v}\cdot\vec{B})\vec{B}-q|\vec{B}|^2\vec{v}$$

In the case when $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{B}$ are orthogonal, $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{B}=0$

You can write $$q\vec{v}=-\frac{\vec{F}\times\vec{B}}{|B|^2}=\frac{\vec{B}\times\vec{F}}{|B|^2}$$

Comment: Thank you. I see now that $ \dfrac {\|\vec {qv}\|^2}{\|\vec {F}\|^2} = \dfrac {1}{\|\vec {B}\|^2} $. How stupid from my side not to see this before.